# How to create a trello card using discord commands?

Tags: api, discord, trello

I am trying to make it so when a user says `?meta <title> <description>` in `#meta` channel, it will grab the username and the two arguments. It will then create a trello card in the `Backlog` list, with the title being `<title> - <username>` and the description being `<description>`.

Any idea on how to approach this, maybe trello api? The user will separate the two arguments with <>. 
For example: `?meta <command bug> <when you do xyz...>`

Any help is much appreciated!